# SOAP statement for WCF Service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I asked about consuming a WCF service from RPG here and received this response:  Scott Klement has a presentation and examples: http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/#HTTPAPI

I used SoapUI to test my service and also to get he soap statement to be used with HTTAPI.  The service returnes data in SoapUI but I have been unsuccessful using it in the RPG program.  SoapUI returns the following, but it seems only to work within SoapUI - it also doesn't include the path to my service which is

```
http://ServerName/COE/CustByNameList.svc
```

If I navigate to `http://ServerName/COE/CustByNameList.svc?wdsl,` I get the wsdl.

Statement returned in SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetCustomerData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:CustomerNumber>1688</tem:CustomerNumber>
      </tem:GetCustomerData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The result looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetCustomerDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><GetCustomerDataResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:List xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebOrderEntry.Lists"><b:PartialCSTMS><b:ADR19A>3910 LAKEFIELD DR             </b:ADR19A><b:ADR29A>JOHNS CREEK FACILITY          </b:ADR29A><b:CITY9A>SUWANEE                  </b:CITY9A><b:CST_x0023_9A>1688</b:CST_x0023_9A><b:NAME9A>JOHNSON CONTROLS              </b:NAME9A><b:PHON9A>770-495-9950        </b:PHON9A><b:STAT9A>GA</b:STAT9A><b:ZIPC9A>30024     </b:ZIPC9A></b:PartialCSTMS></a:List></GetCustomerDataResult></GetCustomerDataResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I keep getting 500 internal server errors.  I've tried numerous variations of the SOAP statement based on the examples I have seen, but they date back to 2008.  Has anyone been successful with calling a WCF service from RPG?

Comment: Another source to ask your question is the [WEB400](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/web400) mailing list. Many of them deal with this all of the time. There is also the [HTTPAPI mailing list](http://www.scottklement.com/ftpapi/ftpapilist.html) where again they are using this API to accomplish this. NOTE: I am a moderator for another list on midrange.com and I know Scott Klement via professional channels..

Comment: I have been speaking with Scott via his forum - I think he is a little frustrsted with my level of i series knowledge. I'll check out the other links you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to throw the towel in on using HTTPAPI to consume my WCF web service - just could not get past HTTP 400 and 500 errors.  Logging wasn't helping.  I believe I finally managed to get the SOAP call correct but then started receiving errors that seemed to translate into special character issues.

Instead, I ended up using IBM's IWS and got it working.  These two links were of great help:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-amrawsdl2rpg/index.html

http://www.iprodeveloper.com/article/rpg-programming/consume-web-services-with-ibms-iws-66209

Answer (score 0):

I asked my Twitter network and [@alexeivbaranov](https://twitter.com/alexeivbaranov) responded with the following:

> Try to compare request & response from SoapUI and your RPG client using TcpMon. As I understand your SoapUI req works fine but RPG req gets 500, so problem in request. Compare them.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to get notified when someone replies - anyway, upon mult variatons of the soap stmt, am now getting error "cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree" Still researching - have found a lot of info, but do not understand how to fix in my situation

Comment: Not sure how to use TcpMon - added error tracing for the http error codes being received to the server which helped

Answer (score 0):

Check your headers. You may be missing the soap action. Here is an example of a request to a WCF service exposed using WsHttp binding with security enabled. wsa:Action is the thing you might need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:ns="http://somenamespace">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Action>http://someuri/Get</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:To>http://localhost/someapp/SomeService.svc</wsa:To>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:GetRequest>
            <ns:Body>
                <ns:Id>12345</ns:Id>
            </ns:Body>
        </ns:GetRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks - I have not seen wsa:Action in any of the examples I have come across - have yet to try it, but am closer - see my comment above.